# Unity collison not detected 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I am building a 2d game and I run this code with a collider on both the other objects (on trigger: on to the other object) but nothing works)The other object is name Coin and also it has the tag Coin.
I added kinematic rigid body to the coin and still no work :( (If I deleted it still the same). Also, my player has to colliders and the collision detected on both coin and player are discrete. Also, they are prefabs both

```
void OnTriggerEnter2d(Collider2D other) {
 Debug.Log("detected");
 if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin")) {
  other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
 }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311845/ontriggerenter-not-working-properly), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313824/unity-ontriggerenter-is-not-being-called), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245309/unity-ontriggerenter-not-registering-collision), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468828/ontriggerenter-not-called), maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360902/why-does-oncollisionenter-not-get-triggered)?

Comment: @Hellium no all of that has been checked but still nothing(Also its 2d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo mistake: instead OnTriggerEnter2d try OnTriggerEnter2D. with a capital D. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a OnTrigger collision triggered, you must have the following requirements:
1-The 2 objects need to have a collider attached it.
2-Only one of the objects needs to be a trigger
3-One of the 2 objects must have a rigidbody attached to it.

Did you fulfill the requirement n°3 ?

Typo mistake: instead OnTriggerEnter2d try OnTriggerEnter2D. with a capital D. ;)

Comment: both of them have rigidbody the one kinematic and the other dynamic (simulated:on)

Comment: That's the hardest to find, when you check everything but the obvious :p